# couldn't scrap the price out of a HTML code

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the HTML code below:

```
<span class="price">
    <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
        <bdi>
             <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">R</span>
             1 579
             <sup>00</sup>
        </bdi>
    </span>
</span>
```

I need to extract the price from there using python in format "1579.00" as a float. how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the price amount as float you can use next example:

```py
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """<span class="price">
    <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
        <bdi>
             <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">R</span>
             1 579
             <sup>00</sup>
        </bdi>
    </span>
</span>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

price = soup.select_one(".amount").text
price = float("".join(re.findall(r"\d+", price))) / 100
print(price)
```

Prints:

```py
1579.0
```

---

Or:

```py
soup.select_one(".woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol").extract()
price = float(
    soup.select_one(".amount")
    .get_text(strip=True, separator=".")
    .replace(" ", "")
)
print(price)
```

Prints:

```
1579.0
```